# Почему не работает подключенный Jackson(2.6.1)? Как подключить Jackson к отдельному модулю?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Допустим, проект называется А, состоит из 4 модулей, как подключить библиотеку не ко всему проекту А, а, например, только ко 2 модулю?

Есть такой код:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.name = "Murka";
        cat.age = 5;
        cat.weight = 3;

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        convertToJSON(writer, cat);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }

    public static void convertToJSON(StringWriter writer, Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(writer, object);
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect
    public static class Cat {
        @JsonProperty("wildAnimal")
        public String name;
        @JsonIgnore
        public int age;
        @JsonProperty("over")
        public int weight;

        Cat() {
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаю в intelliJ 
Вот такую ошибку выдает:

```
Error:(4, 1) java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.core does not exist
Error:(39, 15) java: cannot access 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned
class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникала из-за того, что Jackson подключал ко всему проекту, а не к отдельному модулю проекта. Подключив к отдельному модулю, нужно не забыть удалить lib из всего проекта, иначе эффекта никакого. Если кто-нибудь знает почему может возникать подобная ошибка, напишите ответ, пожалуйста.